# Собственный Bootloader для stm32. Не запускаются прерывания

Tags: stm32

Ld файл bootloader:

```
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 8K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 64K
}
```

Функция перехода в основною программу

```
#define APPLICATION_ADDRESS    0x8003000//адрес начала программы

void Go_To_User_App(void)
{
uint32_t app_jump_address;

typedef void(*pFunction)(void);
pFunction Jump_To_Application;
 __disable_irq();
app_jump_address = *( uint32_t*) (APPLICATION_ADDRESS + 4);    
Jump_To_Application = (pFunction)app_jump_address;            
  __set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t*) APPLICATION_ADDRESS);          
Jump_To_Application();
}
```

Ld файл основного софта:

```
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 8K
FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x8003000,   LENGTH = 64K
}
```

Вектор tab offset:

```
#define VECT_TAB_OFFSET  0x0003000U
```

Если не включены таймеры в основной программе, все отрабатывает корректно.

Проблема, при включении любого таймера программа доходя до таймера прекращает работу,.

Подскажите, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, как решили?

Comment: у меня stm32h7, там надо ещё раскомментировать `/* #define USER_VECT_TAB_ADDRESS */`

Comment: Да я тоже раскоментил, но не помогло

Comment: я так понимаю, у вас обе программы должны быть прошиты одновременно, но они пересекаются, надо наверное FLASH разложить по разным секторам, именно секторам, потому что сектора целиком стираются при прошивке, хотя при запуске одной программы это не причина

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить деиниты

```
#define APPLICATION_ADDRESS    0x8005000//адрес начала программы
```

void Go_To_User_App(void)
{
uint32_t app_jump_address;

```
typedef void(*pFunction)(void);//объявляем пользовательский тип
pFunction Jump_To_Application;//и создаём переменную этого типа


 //__disable_irq();

app_jump_address = *( uint32_t*) (APPLICATION_ADDRESS + 4);
HAL_RCC_DeInit();
HAL_DeInit();

Jump_To_Application = (pFunction)app_jump_address;            //приводим его к пользовательскому типу
__set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t*) APPLICATION_ADDRESS);          //устанавливаем SP приложения
__disable_irq();
SCB->VTOR = APPLICATION_ADDRESS;
__enable_irq();
Jump_To_Application();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему используется HAL, для него нужно сбросить настройки SysTick.

Вместо

```
__disable_irq();
```

надо прописать

```
HAL_RCC_DeInit();
HAL_DeInit();
SysTick->CTRL = 0;
SysTick->LOAD = 0;
SysTick->VAL = 0;
```